# Rule of thumb of pandas to_csv chunksize; how to set chunksize?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

When you write a large dataframe with `df.to_csv(...)`, it sometimes clogs up your memory. Setting `chunksize` helps in that case. See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

What is a good rule to decide on chunksize? Now I just start at 1e6 and then lower it by orders of magnitude until it works.

I imagine some rule of thumb on (MB-free / size_per_row * 0.9). Wondering if someone had a sensible one, ideally programetically determined.

Comment: Have you already tried to set `chunksize` value that is multiple of 1000?

Comment: As you said the optimal value is sensitive to the amount of free memory on your machine so we cannot solve it for you (and the size of your rows). You need to try and err, open your memory manager util and start maybe with high values (in the thousands), lower if needed.

Comment: `0.9` will use 90% of your available memory, that's pretty radical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't go overboard with this. Consider what you gain and lose.

What do you save by using larger in-memory buffers:

- You reduce the number of system calls
- You may reduce the number of network round-trips over network file systems

What do you lose by using larger buffers:

- You spend more memory overall
- You reduce CPU cache efficiency. Memory bandwidth starts becoming a concern once you exceed L2 cache size (typically 128 - 256 kiB) and becomes a major concern once you exceed L3 cache size (a few MiB)

In my experience, for a local file system, transfer sizes of 4 kiB - 64 kiB are good. For network file systems you may want to go larger, e.g. 1 MiB. But there are no hard borders. You just get diminishing returns and at some point a slight slow-down.

Now the issue is that you give the size in rows, not bytes. So this depends on your format. Of course you can estimate the row size but I think this is overkill since, again, you don't need to be precise. With 80 characters per line, you get 51 lines per 4 kiB, 819 lines per 64 kiB, and 13107 lines per 1 MiB. So, going with 100, 1000, or 10,000 lines seems reasonable.

You can of course simply benchmark it.

```py
import sys

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def main():
    outpath = sys.argv[1]
    rows, chunksize = (int(arg) for arg in sys.argv[2:])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data={
        'colA': np.random.random(rows), 'colB': np.random.random(rows),
        'colC': np.random.random(rows), 'colD': np.random.random(rows)})
    df.to_csv(outpath, chunksize=chunksize)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

On my system I get 1 million rows in 4.3s at chunk size 100, 3.6s at 1000, 3.4s at 10,000, and 3.6s at 100,000.

Most of the time is already spent simply formatting the output. Buffer size is rather secondary. Take a reasonable number and be done with it. If anything, spend time switching to a more reasonable, binary format.

Comment: Thanks :) Are those single iteration timings? The scenario where this is relevant for me is a bit more diverse table (strings, etc), but agree that switching to a different format is a the general way to go :)

Comment: @Roelant Those were single iteration timings without warmup or anything. I just did a repeated call comparing 1 to 10 iterations. The overall trend stays the same. I also did some tests just with strings in the datasets to reduce the conversion overhead. That changed the absolute numbers but not the overall trends

Answer (score 1):

One of possible strategies:

```
import psutil

def calc_chunksize(df, share=0.3):
    """Estimate optimal chunksize (in records) for writing large dfs with df.to_csv"""

    # get approximate record size in bytes
    row_size = df.memory_usage(index=True, deep=True).sum() / df.index.size
    # get share of available memory size in bytes
    avail_mem = psutil.virtual_memory().available * share

    return int(avail_mem / row_size)
```

Manage on `share` attribute at your own conscious discretion (consider that other processes depending on their activity may dynamically require some share of available memory).